# Uninstall wine completely

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, wine, node.js

I need to run `sudo apt-get update` and `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -` to install Node.js. However, I get the following error:

```
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/mint bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/Ubuntu_18.10_standard bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

To fix this I decided to completely uninstall wine as I do not require wine. I followed the steps on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/126745/1624964).

For the first part:

```
cd $HOME
rm -r .wine
rm .config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -r .local/share/applications/wine
rm .local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm .local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
```

I received this error `rm: cannot remove '<path>': No such file or directory` for all the `rm` commands.

For the second part:

**Input:** `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine`

**Output:** `Virtual packages like 'wine' can't be removed`

For the third part:

```
sudo apt-get update
 -> E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/mint bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/Ubuntu_18.10_standard bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

sudo apt-get autoclean
-> Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
-> Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 637 not to upgrade.
```

As observed above running `sudo apt-get update` outputs the same errors as before.

After some researching I ran these command in order:

**Input:** `dpkg -l "*wine*" | grep ii`

**Output:**

```
ii  libwine:amd64      3.0-1ubuntu1 amd64        Windows API implementation - library
ii  wine64             3.0-1ubuntu1 amd64        Windows API implementation - 64-bit binary loader
```

**Input:** `sudo apt remove libwine:amd64`

**Output:**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libwine wine64
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 2 to remove and 637 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 193 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 266834 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing wine64 (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libwine:amd64 (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

**Input:** `dpkg -l "*wine*" | grep ii`

**Output:** `dpkg-query: no packages found matching *wine*`

I would like to get rid wine so I am able to install nodejs and not receive the error about release file. I am using Linux Mint 19.2 Tina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve removed Wine, but to fix the `apt update` errors you need to remove the Wine repositories. Look for their definitions with

```
grep -ri wine /etc/apt
```

then edit the corresponding files to remove (or comment, with an introductory `#`) the relevant `deb` lines.